# How to copy files from Windows to Remix OS Player

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I installed `RemixOSPlayerPackage-B2016111403` on *Windows 7 x64* and have some `.apk` files on my Windows machine. How to copy them to the *Remix OS Player* machine for testing those files?

I tried drag and dropping, but it didn't work.

Is there any good way except for upload and downloading the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it is very simple through the Internet. I could solve it using a messenger program like `Telegram` that works fine on both platforms and has the ability of exchanging any kinds of files and text as well.

I put my files on the Windows version of the app and get them on the other platform.